# What is the meaning of "When the straight and narrow get a little too straight?"

Tags: idioms

I can't understand it. Please explain it in simple terms. Thank you.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: This is a meaning-in-context question: you have not given us any context.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not give sufficient context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiom here is a paraphrase (or misinterpretation, if you will) of a passage in the Bible (Matthew 7:13, 14):

> Enter ye in at the strait gate: for wide is the gate, and broad is the
>   way, that leadeth to destruction, and many there be which go in
>   thereat. Because **strait is the gate, and narrow is the way**, which
>   leadeth unto life, and few there be that find it.

Here, "strait" means "tight" (or just narrow, for that matter).

"On the straight and narrow" means leading a highly moral, good and honest life. As in:

> She was a wild girl once, but she's been on **the straight and narrow**
>   for many years now.

"A little too straight" could mean -

1. too constricting, too stifling, not leaving any room for flexibility (like, a person's moral principles not allowing said person to suddenly gain a lot of money or a lot of respect or whatever turns said person on)

or -

2. A person who thinks of him/herself as highly moral is being a hypocrite, "holier-than-thou," and either slows everybody down or gets on everybody's nerves.

or -

3. An immoral person (or persons) find that their associate is too much of a goody-two-shoes, impossible to deal with, because of the associate's actual ... uh ... genuine ... moral principles. As in, he or she will not allow them to bend the law, let alone assist them in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

It means something like ***when following the rules and social mores so exactly that they become boring***. (Or? Depending on the context it could also be a reference to 'straight' as heterosexual. So *when following the moral code means being heterosexual.* Edit: It could also mean *when following the moral code means being boring by not taking drugs.*)

*The straight and narrow* is an image for a straight and narrow path; it's an idiom meaning you act in a moral way and don't break the law -- you don't stray from the path. From Cambridge Dictionary:

[straight and narrow](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/straight-and-narrow)

> If you keep on the straight and narrow, you behave in a way that is
>   honest and moral: The threat of a good beating should keep him on the
>   straight and narrow.

If you call someone 'straight' it can be meant (not always -- sometimes it is a compliment for being direct and honest) in a slightly derogotary sense, as in 'traditional  and conservative to the point of being boring'.

[straight](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/straight)

> informal traditional or serious: disapproving He was a nice enough
>   guy, but he was so straight - I always felt I had to be on my best
>   behaviour with him.

Etymonline makes an association between straight and strait-laced and the straight and narrow path.

[straight](https://www.etymonline.com/word/straight#etymonline_v_24510)

> "conventional," especially "heterosexual," 1941, a secondary sense
>   evolved from straight (adj.1), probably suggested by straight and
>   narrow path "course of conventional morality and law-abiding
>   behavior," which is based on a misreading of Matthew vii.14 (where the
>   gate is actually strait), and the other influence seems to be from
>   strait-laced.

And a '[hippy glossary'](https://www.hipplanet.com/books/atoz/glossary.htm) online gives 'straight' a further nuance.

> Go Straight: To stop using drugs. To get your "act" together.